# List of range from another spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have two spreadsheets, the first sheet has a list of data:

**companies**

```
company A  
company B  
company C
```

In the second sheet I need to create a drop down menu to fetch the companies from the first sheet, so I could choose the company from a list of the previous companies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the Importrange() command to put a copy of the data into a helper-sheet in the 2nd google Sheets file.

And then use the Data Validation function to restrict the values, based on this.